# Use a Python package from a script without installing it

Tags: python, pip, package

I have a python script which will be executed by the system python (on OSX `/usr/bin/python`). This script uses an external  package (in my case [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML)).

How can I provide the package without `pip`-installing it into the system python. I do not want to create a virtual environment for this script either, because the script is meant to run on other "vanilla" OSX machines as well.

I'm thinking of creating a directory under the same path where the script resides and "dumping"  the external package  there. But in what form?  And what do I have to do in my script, so that it "sees" the locally dumped package? Just amend `sys.path`?

Comment: Sometimes I've been successful just downloading the "source package" (.tar.gz, .zip, etc) (in your case I think it's PyYaml) into any directory then append that directory to the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable (OS dependent). On Mac/Linux I just set `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<path_to_python_packages_directory>` , re-load the environment. Then "import the_package" in python. Unfortunately, for some packages that depend on CPython, or "C" source files that go to the OS level, it's not possible, or rarely works, but does for most python packages.

Comment: I tried it with `pyYaml` and it seems like it worked (I could import it), but there are some "C" source files in that package, so it may not work as expected.

Comment: @downshift Thanks for this. It *should* be possible to use just PyYaml's `py`-files, because PyYaml contains according to the doco "both pure-Python and fast LibYAML-based parsers and emitters" (http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML). So aslong as I do not import `CLoader` and `CDumper` from `yaml` I should be fine.

Comment: ok cool, sounds good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As an enhancement to [Synedraacus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3534356/synedraacus)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639220/65889):* (*)

You can copy the whole `yaml` subdirectory of PyYAML into your script directory (which is in the PyYAML zip file `lib/yaml` if you use Python 2 and `lib3/yaml` for Python 3). Then you can use it in your code as if you had PyYaml `pip`-installed. Just write:

```
import yaml
```

This works of course only if you don't want to use the C backend.

---

(*) *I tried to add this detail to Synedraacus's answer, but my edit [got rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15441417). Therefore I add this enhancement as a separate answer.*

Answer (score 1):

You can just copypaste the pyYaml's `*.py` files into your script directory and import them like you would import your own modules. This is not the most beautiful solution, but it works.
If you intend to use C backend, it'd be more difficult. You either need to make sure your installer compiles them correctly, or make platform-dependent distributions with the compiled C modules. But those are there for speed and pure Python code can be enough.